# Trying to build Com0Com - c0clog.h missing file

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, kmdf

I am trying to build Com0Com with the new Visual Studio 2013 and DDK.  Microsoft has changed the way drivers are built quite a bit, but I have been able to create a driver project (KMDF) and add the Com0Com source files to the project. (The build instructions that come with Com0Com don't work with the new way Microsoft has designed for creating device drivers).

When I build however, the compiler can't find c0clog.h and it doesn't seem to be included with the zip file on SourceForge.

Has anyone else attempted to build Com0Com and been able to solve this problem of c0clog.h being missing?

Comment: It is a generated file.  Produced by the message compiler (mc.exe), from the c0clog.mc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the suggestion of @Hans Passant I was able to figure it out:
Put the following as a Pre-Build Event under Build Events:

`mc.exe c0clog.mc`